# Error after lintian check

Tags: package-management, lintian

I was following [this tutorial](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html). But when running this command  `bzr builddeb -- -us -uc` I get an error after the lintian check:

```
E: hello: package-contains-info-dir-file usr/share/info/dir.gz
```

After googling I found [this page](https://lintian.debian.org/tags/package-contains-info-dir-file.html).

I also get this warning:

```
W: hello: wrong-name-for-upstream-changelog usr/share/doc/hello/ChangeLog.O.gz
```

Can anyone explain these error messages to me and help me fix the problem causing them?